# Trying to find information on this silk painting - Presumably from 1666, made for the Kangxi Emperor

Tags: translation, meaning, traditional-characters, classical-chinese, history

This painting was presented to us as follows:
“Xia Summer”. With seals“Chen Quan Xi” and “Nam Ping Kangshi”. Dated 1666.

I've figured out that this does refer to 'The year of the Fire Horse' which corresponds to 1666.

But I don't understand Chinese writing myself and would love to know the name of the artist specifically and any other information described.

[[image: Xia Summer][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwBl2.jpg)

[image: Text Closeup]

[image: Seal closeup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the picture is named “受天百祿”, a verse quoted from 詩 小雅 天保, roughly means:

> And thou receivest every heavenly favour

next line is “康熙丙午夏日沈銓寫”, means in the summer of 1666, drawn by 沈銓 (the author name)

the upper seal is “沈銓之印”

the lower seal is “南蘋”

here’s a wiki page about the author:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shen_Quan

well, most likely, this one is a **fake** product. because, mr 沈 was born in 1682

have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for the information! It's good to have the author.
Is it possible that this painting was made in reference to 1666 or backdated with another reason?
What mostly concerns me now is that this is then perhaps not even a 18th century, but perhaps 19th century version or replica. 
It is definitely painted, and has a decent age. The origins are quite respectable. 
(This is more for taxation / identification purposes, no value has been decided on yet)

Comment: @Jordaens, a google image search "沈銓" "受天百祿" would give you many similar pictures.

Comment: "祿 good fortune" has the same pronunciation as "鹿 deer",